# How to skip first column of data's while parsing chunk by chunk large source file in C#

Tags: c#, sql

Reference Link used:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543789/How-to-parse-chunk-by-chunk-a-large-CSV-file-and-b

I need to skip the first column and the datasets of column 1 present in a large source file and parse only from column two.

I am new to this c# and Sql

Code is present in the given link.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
sr.ReadLine(); // add this line
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
```